# Java convert timestamp object to date format

Tags: java, android, timestamp

In my Android app, I'm showing an `List<Object>`, it contains **String**, **int** and **Timestamp** values, and I don't know which item is the Timestamp one.
Now it appears like this: Timestamp(seconds=1556208432, nanoseconds=754000000)

What I wanna do is parse this into a readable Date format.
Here's the code I tried:

```
TextView t2 = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
String tS2 = String.valueOf(values.get(position));

if(tS2.contains("Timestamp(seconds=")) {
    long ts = Timestamp.parse(tS2);
    Date date = new Date(ts);
    Log.d(TAG, "date: "+date);
} else {
    t2.setText(tS2);
}
```

And parse it with SimpleDateFormat, like this:

```
String myFormat = "yyyy MMM dd";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
t2.setText(sdf.format(something));
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at java.util.Date.parse

**EDIT1:**

It dies with the error below when it gets to the Date part.

```
Object time = values.get(position);
com.google.firebase.Timestamp ts = (com.google.firebase.Timestamp) time;
String str = ts.toString();
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str));
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Timestamp(seconds=1556208432, nanoseconds=754000000)"

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @matanper Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the `timestamp` to `string` which **will not convert the value it's holding to string but describe the object itself**.

To get the date of the Firebase timestamp just call `toDate()` on it.

For more info [check this out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)